# Делаю двумерный массив из file(txt), где ключами будут дни недели. Важно знать, что дней точно 7 или указать какой отсутствует

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Txt-файл берется построчно при помощи `$arrayofStr = file('txt-файл');` 
- `file_get_contents` не пойдет. Там есть строки, содержащие дни недели разного вида ("Понедельник", "ПОНЕДЕЛЬНИК" или "понедельник, 15 октября"; кстати, дни недели всегда в начале строки). Файл должен содержать 7 разных дней. Как сделать так, чтобы выводить сообщение о том, какой конкретный день отсутствует в массиве? Вообще цель - впоследствии сделать из $arrayofStr двумерный массив, где ключи первого порядка - дни недели. Сейчас я делаю так:

```
$weekArray = [];
$now = -1;
foreach($arrayOfStr as $str){
    if(preg_match('/^Понедельник|^Вторник|^Среда|^Четверг|^Пятница|^Суббота|^Воскресенье/ui', $str)){
        $now++;
    }
    else{
        if($now > -1){
            $weekArray[$now][] = $str;
        }
    }
}
```

Потом делал `count($weekArray)`, и, если `count < 7`, делал `echo 'Проверьте дни недели'`, но это недостаточно информативно... Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Можете оставить входные данные, и какие должно быть после обработки, хотя бы примерные?

Comment: Так и не понял, как загружать сюда текстовой файл для примера.

`Понедельник, 01 Октября  
10:00, 09:36 Аэропорт для животных  
10:25, 19:30 Как выжить животным?  
11:15, 20:25 Полиция Феникса: Отдел по защите животных  
Вторник, 02 Октября  
10:00, 09:36 Аэропорт для животных  
10:25, 19:30 Как выжить животным?  
11:15, 20:25 Полиция Феникса: Отдел по защите животных  
Среда, 03 Октября  
10:00, 09:36 Аэропорт для животных  
10:25, 19:30 Как выжить животным?
...`

Comment: На выходе должно быть `$arr = [
'Понедельник'=>
[
    [0] => 10:00 Аэропорт для животных
    [1] => 10:25 Как выжить животным?
    [2] => 11:15 Полиция Феникса: Отдел по защите животных
    [3] => 12:10 Живой или вымерший
    [4] => 14:00 Природа Ближнего Востока
    [5] => 14:55 На свободу с питбулем]
]
, 'Вторник'=>
    [0] => 10:00 Аэропорт для животных
    [1] => 10:25 Как выжить животным?
    [2] => 11:15 Полиция Феникса: Отдел по защите животных
    [3] => 12:10 Живой или вымерший
    [4] => 14:00 Природа Ближнего Востока
    [5] => 14:55 На свободу с питбулем']
...];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function checkDays($arr){

    $week = [
    'Понедельник', 
    'Вторник', 
    'Среда', 
    'Четверг', 
    'Пятница', 
    'Суббота', 
    'Воскресенье'
    ];

    $new = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($week); $i++){
        foreach($arr as $key=>$item){
            if( preg_match("~^{$week[$i]}~ui", $arr[$key]) ){
                $new[$i] = $week[$i];
            }
        }
    }

    if( array_diff($week, $new) ){
        foreach(array_diff($week, $new) as $item){
            echo $item . ' не найден(-а) или написан(-а) с ошибками!' . '<br>';
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, сверяя с заранее созданным массивом, в которым дни недели в нужном порядке:

```
$week = [
    'понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг', 
    'пятница', 'суббота', 'воскресенье'
];

$arrayofStr  = [
    'понедельник, 15 октября', 'вторник', 'СРЕДА', 'Четверг', 'пятнц', 
    'суб_бота', 'воскресенье'    
];

if (count($week) == count($arrayofStr))
{
    foreach ($week as $key => $value)
        $new[] = (preg_match('/^'.preg_quote($value).'/ui', $arrayofStr[$key]))
        ? $arrayofStr[$key]
        : 'Не найден день - '.$value;

} else {
    echo 'Проверьте данные';
}

print_r($new);
```